# Get the 18 first results in a SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml-parsing, slice

I have this xml response to which I will do a

```
foreach($response->entry->item as $data)
```

but $data contains more arrays (20) than I need (18). So I tried doing array_slice but as you know it won't work.

What other solutions could I try?

Comment: lol, obvious... trying right now. Thank you very much.

Comment: you do it like you would with any other array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try restricting the result set from the data you select from your xml via xpath.

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <document>
        <item id="1" />
        <item id="2" />
        <item id="3" />
        <item id="4" />
        <item id="5" />
        <item id="6" />
    </document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump($xml->xpath("//item[@id>2 and @id<5]")) // Prints the two nodes matching the condition from the xpath
```

As was suggested from the comments you could also just loop over the array with `for` instead of `foreach` and restrict the number of iterations.

Comment: I will try a for as @k102 suggested, I think it's better that way. Tnx